# Microsoft Excel Userform change cell colour if ListBox contains certain words?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, forms

I am currently making an excel document to sort certain products, and show what components they contain. In my A Column, is the components, and in Row 1 is my products. I currently have 2 User Forms, 1 to add new components and another for new products. In my form for new products, I have the option to select any component that is in the 1st Column in a listbox, and then add it to a second listbox. I am now however unable to continue, I would like the corresponding cells between each product and its components to change colour depending on whether if uses each component. The UserForm code is:

```
Private Sub AddList_Click()
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then ListBox2.AddItem ListBox1.List(i)
Next i
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ListBox1.Value = ""
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Unload Me
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
If ListBox2.Contains("#A2") Then

MsgBox "Please enter condition in notes"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    ListBox2.Clear
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0

For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Selected(i - counter) Then
        ListBox2.RemoveItem (i - counter)
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     For i = 1 To 500
            ListBox1.AddItem Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add "TRUE" to each cell **value** in the product column which matched the component. Then use standard conditional formatting to highlight the cells that contain the value TRUE. If you don't want to see text values in the cells, make the default text colour white and the conditional formatting text colour the same as the cell fill colour.

In rough pseudo code:

```
'insert new product in row 1
newproductcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Cells(1, newproductcol).Value = Textbox1.value

'now find components
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
For j = 0 To listboxcount - 1
    If listboxitemvalue(j) = cells(i,1).value then 
        cells(i, newproductcol).Value = TRUE
        exit for
    end if
Next j
Next i
```